# URI segment equivalent in Zend-framework?

Tags: zend-framework, codeigniter, uri

I'm trying to read the first uri segment after the base URL.
In CodeIgniter I would just do `$this->uri->segment(1);` but how do I do this in zend-framework?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hi Depending if you are using modules or not

```
$request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
$request->getModuleName(); // null if default
$request->getControllerName();
$request->getActionName();
```

you can also get the value of any parameter through

```
$request->getParam('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

www.example.com/id/idnumber

```
$this->_getParam("id");
```